# language translation independent of qt version

Tags: linux, qt, translation

On my system I am using lrelease version of qt4.7.
I have generated qm file which is working fine in production environment.

But unfortunately our server uses lrelease version of qt3.3
and qm file generated from same ts file on server giving junk characters on production environment.

I got a suggestion of converting special characters of other languages ( french & Italian ) to hex code and its working fine.

But as I got large ts file, it is hard to change each special character to hex code.
Could you please suggest some fix ( besides changing lrelease version on server)
or any tool which converts special characters to hex code in ts files?

Comment: Change lrelease on your system? :) Seriously - why not add Qt 3 separately?

Comment: but qt3.3 is not successfully translating special characters mentioned in ts file directly, qt3 requires hex code to successfully translate french characters.

Comment: I am using encoding="iso88591" in ts file for french language.

Answer (score 0):

This works as designed. If your application runs on Qt4, use the Qt4 tools to generate the .qm files. Using Qt3's tools will not work.

Comment: but if I am using hex code for special characters its working fine on qt4 even if it is built from qt3 tools.

Comment: That's called "pure luck". It's great that the developers have not managed to break the compatibility completely, but just don't rely on that. You are wasting the time on this.